# self.close() backtrader : not able to close the trade as intended

Tags: backtrader

Whenever an order gets bought or sold or closed in the "next(self)" method, the corresponding order.isbuy() or issell() methods get executed in the notify_order(self, order) method. I am OK with isbuy() and issell() methods being called whenever there is a self.buy() or self.sell() execution at "next(self)", but for self.close() I would like to identify in notify_order(self, order) that the call is for close and not for buy or sell and take appropriate actions. If someone who is well verse with backtrader can advise that would be great

````
def notify_order(self, order):
        if order.status in [order.Submitted, order.Accepted]:
            # Buy/Sell order submitted/accepted to/by broker - Nothing to do
            return
        if order.isbuy():
           pass
        elif order.issell():
           pass

def next(self):
      if self.order == None:
         return
                  if pos == 0:
                    #logic 
                    self.order = self.buy()

                elif #logic:
                    self.order = self.sell()
            else:
                if pos > 0:
                    if  #logic:
                        self.order = self.close()
                else:
                    if  #logic:
                        self.order = self.close()```




I tried tweaking the logic various ways, but I couldn't achieve the end result
````